# how to draw multiple lines in ggline

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I ran a regression first and manually calculated three fitted values based on coefficients and confidence interval. The data frame looks like this. `yld` is the fitted values calculated with coefficients, `yld.l` and `yld.u` are fitted values calculated with lower and upper confidence intervals.

```
> head(m.m.m)
      harv   frez_j    dd_j  cupc_j    sm7_j fitted_j max_spring_j sp_spring_j pc_spring_j       lt       qt      yld
1 31793.35 320.0668 2437.82 13.0822 50.63953 46.94146     23.34035   0.0844567    3.260585 18.09834 409.1669 48.78323
2 31793.35 320.0668 2407.26 13.0822 50.63953 46.94146     23.34035   0.0844567    3.260585 18.09834 409.1669 48.73291
3 31793.35 320.0668 2638.01 13.0822 50.63953 46.94146     23.34035   0.0844567    3.260585 18.09834 409.1669 48.90514
4 31793.35 320.0668 2838.45 13.0822 50.63953 46.94146     23.34035   0.0844567    3.260585 18.09834 409.1669 48.72009
5 31793.35 320.0668 2944.05 13.0822 50.63953 46.94146     23.34035   0.0844567    3.260585 18.09834 409.1669 48.52131
6 31793.35 320.0668 2765.93 13.0822 50.63953 46.94146     23.34035   0.0844567    3.260585 18.09834 409.1669 48.81819
         yld.l        yld.u
1 7.006441e-09 339659325071
2 7.272086e-09 326577117107
3 5.525450e-09 432853975445
4 4.400996e-09 539343282695
5 3.918681e-09 600793423028
6 4.773276e-09 499283037958
```

I want to draw three lines with y being `yld`,`yld.l`,`yld.u`, respectively, and x being `dd_j`. I can successfully draw one line with the code below and have no idea how to draw all three.

```
ggline(data=m.m.m,x='dd_j',y='yld',color = 'red',numeric.x.axis = T)
```

Any ideas?

BTW, I think it's extremely inconvenient that in ggplot and ggpubr you have to convert a wide format table to a long format in order to draw multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using ggplot2, dplyr and tidyr**

At first, `ggplot` format could be quite confusing as most of time you have to re-organize your data in function of the atypical grammar of `ggplot`. 
However, if you are using tools provided by `dplyr` and `tidyr`, it could become quite straightforward and requires only few lines of code.

Here, we organize your data as this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df = df %>% select(., dd_j, yld, yld.l, yld.u) %>% pivot_longer(., -dd_j,names_to = "condition", values_to = "Value")
```

And we plot them using ggplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = dd_j, y = Value, color = condition)) + geom_line()
```

[image]
**Alternative using plot**

Alternatively, you can plot your dataset without re-organizing them using `plot`:

```r
xvec = "dd_j"
yvec = c("yld","yld.l","yld.u")
color = c("black", "blue","red")
for(i in 1:length(yvec))
{
  if(i ==1) {
    plot(x = df[,xvec], 
         y = df[,yvec[i]], 
         type = "l", 
         ylim = c(0,max(df[,yvec])), 
         col = color[i])
  }
  else
  {
    lines(x = df[,xvec], 
          y = df[,yvec[i]],
          type = "l", 
          col = color[i])
  }
}
```

[image]

**Data :**
I used only a small sample of your data as provided by your `head`

```r
df = data.frame(harv = rep(31793.5,6),
                dd_j = c(2437.82,2407.26,2638.01,2838.45,2944.05,2765.93),
                yld  = c(48.78,48.73,48.90,48.72,48.52,48.82),
                yld.l = c(7.00,7.27,5.53,4.40,3.91,4.77),
                yld.u = c(3396,3265,4328,5393,6008,4992))
df
```